# after SSHing into another machine and starting vim, run terminal command in original terminal

Tags: ssh, vim, terminal, tmux

I use ssh to remotely login to a machine where I subsequently work primarily from Vim. Sometimes I want to run some shell command on my original machine without leaving Vim. What is a non-disruptive way to do this that can make decisions based on something in the remote server?

For example, I might highlight a URL from Vim on the remote terminal, and then want to launch a browser on my local machine that navigates to this website. It shouldn't matter, but I am using cygwin from a Windows 7 PC.

I have never used tmux, but I was thinking maybe it would help facilitate this?

Comment: Take a look at `man screen`

Comment: @EugenRieck tmux is an alternative to screen. I think if I start using screen or tmux, I would prefer tmux if it can do what I need. Most people seem to prefer tmux. Can you confirm screen can actually be used for this? I don't have it installed yet, I just recently installed tmux though.

Comment: Screen can do this and much more. Start screen, then Ctl-A C to create a second window, from which you start your ssh. With Ctrl-A N you can now toggle between the local and the remote window in the same terminal

Comment: @EugenRieck Ok, but could you send a command back to the local window based on text displayed in the remote window, such as a URL?

Comment: I typically use primary clipboard for that

Comment: @EugenRieck Hmm.. that is not what I am going for from a workflow perspective. What I would really like to do is run some Vim command that sends a command back to the local machine based on text it is displaying. I know how to make vim execute any valid terminal command, so this is not really a vim specific  question. I just need some way to tie them together for back and forth communication, the client and remote machine that is.

Comment: Not a problem. Use ssh -L and then start vim with stderr redirected to nc. Use nc -e on the local side. I don't use vim, but have done this quite often with other cli tools

Comment: Is using vim locally an option? In that case you could use `netrw` to access the remote file, then you could use `system()` or `:!` directly to access your local machine.

Comment: @mMontu Actually most of the time I want commands to run on the remote machine. But there are some special cases where I want them to run on the local computer.

Comment: @EugenRieck, I tried that. The remote machine keeps saying the port is already in use. I tried many different ports, I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the remote vim to make a ssh back to the local machine. [You can setup the public key](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) ([this guide is specific for windows/cygwin](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html)) so you wouldn't be prompt to enter the password.

Clearly it won't run on the original terminal, but for your example case it doesn't seems to be a problem.

As you are running in windows you would probably need to install a ssh daemon; [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows) provides some options.